# Left join to an unreachable database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have a stored procedure on database `A`.
Let's call this stored procedure `sp_a`.
In this stored procedure, I wish to do a left join on a table on another database, database `B`.
Let's call this table `tbl_b`.

So, I would write something like:

```
use A

select *
from tbl_a a
left join B.dbo.tbl_b b on a.ID = b.AID
```

This would work it database `B` is up and running.
But sometimes, this is not the case. However, I would like my stored procedure to just ignore that database `B` "does not exist" and just ignore the left join.
I know before I call my stored procedure if database `B` is reachable.
How do I prevent having to write my whole stored procedure twice, with the only difference that I don't include the left join if I know that database `B` is unreachable?

Comment: Hint:  `IF` is needed for this.

Comment: You won't need to write your PROC twice but you will need to duplicate any code that uses that database.  You would need to check if the database is reachable and pass a flag into your proc to say whether it is available or not and then based on that flag run code with or without the join.

An alternate option would be to create a temp table with a structure that contains the data that you would get from the other database.  Insert the data into that table when it's available and replace the table in your query with the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HAS_DBACCESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-dbaccess-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
IF HAS_DBACCESS('[database name]') = 1
 begin    
  select *
  from tbl_a a
  left join B.dbo.tbl_b b on a.ID = b.AID
 end
else 
  begin
        select *
        from tbl_a a
 end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment but I'm looking for a way so that I don't have to write the select twice, which is the case here.

Comment: there is no way you can do it without two selects